# Regular expression to detect exactly "071-XXXXXXX" where X is a digit

Tags: c#, regex, digit

im looking for a regex which can be used to detect exactly "071-xxxxxxx" where x is a digit.
for an example 0712-954900 matches the scenario.can anyone help me.I tried following code.But it is not working.

```
    string phoneNumber = "0712954900";
    Regex regEx = new Regex(@"\b0\7\1\-\d\d\d\d\d\d\d");
    if (regEx.IsMatch(phoneNumber))
    {
          //do something
    }
```

Comment: Can you be clearer about the use of dashes? Should they be required/forbidden/ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Regular expression to detect exactly “071-XXXXXXX” where X is a digit

Here your are:

```
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"^071-[0-9]{7}$");
```

But it will not execute `// do something` for your sample code, because it's missing the hyphen.

Comment: Thank you MarcinJuraszek.. I tried your answer and it is working for me.Now i can customize it according to my requirement.Thank u again :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
string phoneNumber = "071-2954900";
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"071[-][\d]{7}");
if (regEx.IsMatch(phoneNumber))
{
      //do something
}
```

check [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3bv)

Answer (score 1):

`^071-.{7,7}$` This regex will match `071-&7digit number` for ex:`071-9864527`

Answer (score 1):

This will match the phone number even with or without the "-"

```
 Regex regEx = new Regex(@"^\d{3}\-?\d{7}$");
```